# Add left value for masonry in jQuery

Tags: wordpress, jquery-masonry

I have used the masonry to show my all post in wordpress. There is a div called post-wrap.
In the post all the posts are displayed and in the left side top corner post-type are displayed as menu like

post1
post2
post3

all posts are displayed under a same class div called 'single-post' and all comes under post-wrap div. when i used the masonry here. the masonry by default create a div which is over the post-wrap and it is position relative. So i cant used my menu as well. Now i want display all the elements under masonry div starting with left: 340px;.

Is there any setting for masonry  place change or position changes.

Comment: A link would really help with this question, its difficult to visualise what you are asking for but have you looked at the Masonry cornerstamp?

Comment: Now i want to know about the $.Mason.prototype.resize in jQuery masonry